# I can't open my games hub and sign in to xbox

Tags: games

Hi I can't open my Games Hub how can I sign in to my xbox account? Since The Sims freeplay requires me to sign in xbox to have neighbors

Comment: *Why* can't you sign in? Are you getting an error message? Is the phone  connected to WiFi, or is this over the mobile network? Can you log in to the Xbox website from Internet Explorer on your phone?